# Remove Characters From The foreach Result PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to remove the `""` from the product name and tried various methods but nothing seems to work.

```
foreach ($result as $item) {
    trim($item->item_name, '""');
    echo $item->item_name." ".$item->qty."<br >";
}
```

I want the output to be

```
First Product 4
Second Product 3
```

But this is the output I am getting

```
"First Product" 4
"Second Product" 3
```

Comment: Seems like its inserted with the quotes - just fix that instead and the rest will follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't assign result of `trim` to any variable:

```
foreach ($result as $item) {
    $trimmedName = trim($item->item_name, '"');  // one " is enough
    echo $trimmedName." ".$item->qty."<br >";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a better approach to not insert the quotes to begin with (that is, trim it away before inserting the record into MySQL).

But, if you want to do a PHP-fix when displaying it, you need to return the value of `trim()` - it's not a function by reference.

```php
foreach ($result as $item) {
    $item_name = trim($item->item_name, '"'); // Assign it to a value
    echo $item_name." ".$item->qty."<br >";
}
```

You can also do this directly in the query if you rather want that.

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree that inserting the name without any quotation marks to begin with is better, you can also remove the `"` with `str_replace()`

```
foreach ($result as $item) {
  $newName = str_replace('"', '', $item->item_name);
  echo $newName . " " . $item->qty . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Note that this would also remove quotes in the middle of the string.

Comment: true but for this special case it works. I just took the example he gave.